# Replacing a JSON array in MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I am trying to replace data in a JSON array inside a JSON array in my MySQL Database.

The array looks like this:

```
{"slug": "SLUG","price": "{"44":12,"_default":12}", "test": "TEST"}
```

Now I would like to update the two fields inside the price array.

I am using the following code to be able to replace the price array with a string or number, but I am not able to replace it with another array:

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET productDynamicFields = JSON_REPLACE(productDynamicFields,'$.price', '$test')
        Where productSlug = '$productSlug'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

As you can see I am using a variable called `$test`.

I tried giving the variable the following value: `$test = ['44' => 13, '_default' => 13];` and then encoding it like this: `$test = json_encode($test);`

But now in my database it looks like this:

`"price": "{\"44\":13,\"_default\":13}`

I now tried using `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` with no success.

What can I do to achieve the array inside the array?

Comment: Provide a better example .. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as it is not clear if JSON structures could have multiple price items or not in the same JSON structure or have to deal with more records..

Comment: The JSON structure will always be the same. I just need to be able to edit the values of '44' and the value of '_default'. I also HAVE TO use PHP for this, because it is working togheter with another script I am using.

Comment: Well in that case check if @GMB 's answer is workable for your case..  Don't forgot adding a `WHERE` clause to GMB `UPDATE` suggestion, as i am pretty sure you need it..

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you @Dharman I will look at this

Comment: @Dharman is right , but topicstarter do not confuse/mistake the JSON path `$.price` as a PHP variable when rewritting ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than generating json from php and attempting to pass it to MySQL, you would better use MySQL function `json_object()` to generate a valid json object:

```
update t
set js = json_replace(js, '$.price', json_object('44', 13, '_default', 13))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e08b87e55455e8c383b6ef72586f107)**:

```
create table t (js json);
insert into t values('{"slug": "SLUG","price": {"44":12,"_default":12}, "test": "TEST"}');

update t
set js = json_replace(js, '$.price', json_object('44', 13, '_default', 13));

select * from t
```

```
| js                                                                    |
| :-------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"slug": "SLUG", "test": "TEST", "price": {"44": 13, "_default": 13}} |
```

Note:

> The array looks like this:
>
> `{"slug": "SLUG","price": "{"44":12,"_default":12}", "test": "TEST"}`

- this is a json *object* (with an embedded json object under key `"price"`), not a json array
- you had additional double quotes around the embedded object that made the json invalid, I assumed that was a typo and removed them

Comment: Yes! I got it working! I used: `$sql = "UPDATE products SET productDynamicFields = JSON_REPLACE(productDynamicFields,'$.price', JSON_OBJECT('44',$test,'_default',$test)) WHERE productSlug = '$productSlug'";` I will now look at the security of my script. :)